# Qt - Capturing QKeyEvent from /dev/input/event1 in embedded linux device (EGLFS)

Tags: c++, qt5, embedded-linux, qkeyevent, eglfs

I'm trying to get **QKeyEvents** on keypress/keyrelease on linux embedded device(**EGLFS**) which uses custom keypad.
**/dev/input/event1** is the keyevent file.

With **evtest** the output is as expected. But in the Qt application running on EGLFS platform, the eventfilter detects the event type as
**QEvent::SockAct** whenever key is pressed/released on custom keypad. The expected event type is **QEvent::KeyPress/QEvent::KeyRelease** which I'm not able to get.

I've tried setting the below **environment variables**,

> QT_QPA_EVDEV_KEYBOARD_PARAMETERS=/dev/input/event1;grab=1 QT_QPA_GENERIC_PLUGINS=evdevmouse,evdevkeyboard
> QT_QPA_PLATFORM=eglfs
> QT_QPA_EGLFS_DISABLE_INPUT = 1

Before setting these variables, I wasn't able to get any event on key press/release. But after setting these, it is detected as QEvent::SockAct.

Please suggest what needs to be set to get QKeyEvent on key press/release. **Qt Version 5.14** running on embedded linux.

Answer (score 0):

I have never programmed for any embedded platform, but I found that `QEvent::SockAct` is the event that occurs when

> Socket activated, (and it's) used to implement `QSocketNotifier`.

And that

> The `QSocketNotifier` class provides support for monitoring activity
> on a file descriptor.

[here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsocketnotifier.html#QSocketNotifier)

I suppose that if you `open()` `/dev/input/event1` you will get this file descriptor. I know I didn't provide a full solution, but as I said I have never done this kind of programming.

Answer (score 0):

input was read by /dev/input/event
not by qt app,
what worked for me,

try exporting the variable thru script
QT_QPA_GENERIC_PLUGINS = evdevkeyboard, then
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=./ binNAme -platform linuxfb